# how to choose unwanted commit not being accepted by another collaborator?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Let's say that I have 4 commit on my GitHub, and I already sent a pull request to another collaborator. But on those 4 commit, there is 1 commit, I don't wish my collaborator accept that file. How can we do that? As far as I try, there is only a button which show automatically merge (if there is no conflict), and we can't choose which commit we want to accept.

Second is, I have 1 commit which already exist on my Github, and I don't send any pull request  to another collaborator (in this case, there are pending pull request which have not been pull by another collaborator). But once the collaborator pull the files, the commit which I didn't send will be included automatically. So I don't see that pull request is useful here. while we  still can get all the updated data without sending a pull request.

So my main question is, is there any other way to choose which commit we want another collaborator to accept? Because sometimes, I don't want my collaborator accept the commit/files first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I try, there is only a button which show automatically merge (if there is no conflict), and we can't choose which commit we want to accept.

In a similar way you're using Git to locally commit before pushing to GitHub, nothing prevents your collaborator from pulling **your** fork from GitHub, merging locally then pushing back in **his** fork the merged commits.

GitHub only adds a "shortcut" to merge the pull requests. It's **not** the one and sole way to do it.

Considering your question, you have to use Git. GitHub UI only works for straightforward merge. Your collaborator has two exclusive options:

- **[cherry-pick](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-cherry-pick.html)** 3 of the 4 commits by hand
- merge 4 the 4 commits, then **[revert](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-revert.html)** the unwanted commit

A last option would put the burden on your shoulder:

- Create a local branch pointing at the first commit
- Cherry pick the two remaining commits that you're interested in
- Push this branch and open a **new** pull request from it

> But once the collaborator pull the files, the commit which I didn't send will be included automatically.

It looks like you're committing on `master`. Usually, each developer creates one branch per topic (a bug or a new feature). All the work related to this topic is performed in this branch. Once this is finished, you push this branch, open a pull request from it.

Either the pull request is merged, and the next time you'll pull from the mainstream repository, your work will now be integrated in the master branch. Or the pull request has been refused and you can get rid of this topic branch or rework it.

From time to time, it may occur the topic branch is too old to be merged without conflicts. The maintainer may require from you to **[rebase](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-rebase.html)** your branch on top of the current HEAD and `force-update` your pull request with this updated branch.

This quite complete post will help you getting in the details of this **[Git workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)**.